# To prove that a function is linear or two series are convergent

Tags: calculus, integration

> Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and let
> $\{a_n\}_n$ and $\{b_n\}_n$ be sequences of real numbers such that:
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1|f(x)-a_nx-b_n|\text{dx}=0$$
>
> Prove that:
>
> a$)$ The sequences $\{a_n\}_n$ and $\{b_n\}_n$ are convergent
>
> b$)$ The function $f$ is linear

In this particular problem  which was given in an entrance examination of $10+2$ level,my approach was to do the epsilon delta definition of limit with integration ,but of no avail.
I cannot start and arrive at the result... Kindly help anyone.

Comment: I think once you have proven a), b) follows if you can prove that the limit can be interchanged with the integral. In fact I think that the result is $f = ax + b$, where $a$ is the limit of the first sequence and $b$ is the limit of the second one. I'm not sure though.

Comment: @Maths lover: I have the elementary proof I think you may be looking for at the [above link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140000/lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-01-fx-a-nx-b-n-dx-0-implies-a-n-n-b-n)

Comment: Yes.... Thanks..matematleta

Answer (score 0):

Hints only. First, note that $N$ defined on $E=\mathbb{R}^2$ by $N(u,v)=\int_0^1|ux+v|dx$ is a norm. As all the norms on $E$ are equivalent (and ${\rm Max}\{|u|,|v|\}$ is another norm on $E$) there exists a $c>0$ such that $c{\rm Max}\{|u|,|v|\} \leq \int_0^1|ux+v|dx$ for all $(u,v)$. Now put $w_n=\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)-a_nx-b_n|dx$. We have that $|(a_m-a_n)x+b_m-b_n|\leq |f(x)-a_nx-b_n|+|f(x)-a_mx-b_m|$, hence $c{\rm Max}\{|a_m-a_n|,|b_m-b_n|\}\leq w_n+w_m$. Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Kelenner.. The problem is asked in a 10+2 level question.... So the above solution is beyond my level... It would be beneficial if a answer with knowledge up-to 10+2 level is used